# Workaround for all rule and `rules.rule_A.output.output_X` syntax

Tags: snakemake

Recent versions of snakemake allow (and encourage) rules to access the outputs of other rules, such as `rules.rule_A.output.ouput_1`.  This leads to dramatically less repetition and mistakes.  However, this approach doesn't work for the `all` rule, because it necessarily lives first in the Snakefile and thus cannot access the yet-to-be-defined rules.

As a workaround, I've found a workaround in which the `all` rule has a single input, `checkpoint`, and a `checkpoint` rule, which lives at the end of the Snakefile and enumerates the desired final outputs `rules.rule_X.output.output_Y`.  However, I find this workaround to be somewhat contrived (leads to issues where the checkpoint isn't touched but its inputs are) and I was curious if anyone has a better approach.  It might also be possible to patch Snakemake so that the `all` rule could resides at the *end* of the Snakefile, although I'm not sure whether this is feasible or not.

Do folks here have any suggestions on whether there are cleaner arounds like the one I discussed---or whether a patch to Snakemake might clean this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The all rule can indeed live at the end of the Snakefile. You just have to invoke snakemake -- all.

Comment: This is a reasonable solution and only costs an extra 6 characters.  I can't recall if there are any other "special" properties of the first / "all" rule that are used when workflows are included via any of the include / subworkflow mechanisms.